# Problem connecting AS400 (V7R3M0) with SQL Server 2017 via ODBC Link Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ibm-midrange

I have a problem connecting AS400 (V7R3M0) with SQL Server 2017 via ODBC Link Server. It is very slow.

```
SELECT * 
FROM AS400.CATALOG.LIBDTA.TABLE1 
WHERE ...
```

How to fix this? If you don't want to use `OPENQUERY`

Thanks

Comment: Try using the OLE DB provider included with [IBM i Access - Client solutions](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions). Linked servers must ultimately use an OLE DB provider so the MSDASQL OLE DB provider (Microsoft OLE DB provider for ODBC drivers) is used on top of ODBC when ODBC drivers are used for linked servers.

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix this? If you don't want to use OPENQUERY

You can't...MS in their infinite wisdom decided that the way a (non-MS?) linked server would work is that the entire table would be pulled back and the where performed locally.

If you use `OPENQUERY`, then the SQL is sent to the linked server, executed and only the results are returned.

I supposed if your `WHERE` clause is static, you could set up a view on the IBM i side, then just query the view.  But those use cases are few and far between.